# How to create a powershell script that reads an xml file that has just been created?

Tags: xml, powershell

I am using Bamboo to create a an .xml file that will read all the attributes that I require.  At the moment my script looks like this:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content C:\Users\c.d\TestResult.xml
foreach ($Success in $XmlDocument.'test-results')
{
   Write-Host  $XmlDocument.'test-results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-case'.success
   Write-Host $XmlDocument.'test-results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-case'.result 
}
```

This all works perfectly fine but as you can see this is me having to go through so many child nodes just to get to the attributes I need (and this is a relatively small amount of tests for this project)

The problem is that the script will be used for many .xml results files, so some with have a greater amount of child node paths than others but all with have the final attributes that I need, so I was trying to figure out if I could just serach for the final attribute e.g. **success** by doing somethign like "~/.success" or "//success" but everything I have tried will not display anything then, is there a way of doing this?

For example if this was my xml file

```
<myUsers>
<Users> 
  <User> 
    <Name>a</Name> 
  </User> 
  <User> 
    <Name>b</Name> 
  </User> 
</Users>
</myUsers>
```

Instead of doing:

```
   Write-Host $userfile.'myUsers'.'Users'.'User'.Name
```

Can I do:

```
   Write-Host '~/'.Name
```

Also I should note that in me example the node names that are create as the exact same so I don't know if this would affect the solution.

Comment: yes, please post an example file.

Comment: @MartinBrandl how can I do this the file is over 1000 lines of xml

Comment: You could upload the file using a file upload provider like http://www.file-upload.net/ .

Comment: I edited in a smaller example if that helps

Comment: You're looking for [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx). Use the [`SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.aspx) or [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode.aspx) method to select nodes from an XML document with an XPath filter.

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks